# how to retrieve all table names used to map an entity?

Tags: java, jpa

i'd like to get a list of table names used to store an entity in the database.
the list should contain the table of the main entity itself, of course, and all tables that were created as result of XtoX relationships present on this entity.

i know i could examine the class and infer the table names based on annotations on the class or JPA standard naming conventions if no annotations are present, but that doesn't seem very safe.

is there a way i could query the jpa for this information?

Comment: Parsing annotations _is_ safe. It's exactly the same (given you don't have bugs in your parser) as the JPA provider does.

Comment: @MarcelStör its the case where that aren't any annotations that im worried about, conventions might change...

Comment: True, but if conventions change so do your table names. Of course you wouldn't write the parser from scratch but hook into the parsers of your favorite (open source) JPA provider.